# Why does ReactiveUI's ToProperty on an ObservableForProperty cause a FailInit in F#

Tags: .net, f#, reactiveui

In ReactiveUI 5.2.0 and F# 3.1, the following F# code causes an InvalidOperationException when constructing the object (from a C# WPF app)

The message is "The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized" and it occurs during a read of the property passed into `ObservableForProperty` (although the default is to skip the initial value).

```
type MyVM() as this =
inherit ReactiveObject()

let source : obj = obj()

let ofp =            
    this.ObservableForProperty([|"Source"|])
         .Select(fun x -> x.Value)
        .ToProperty(this, (fun y -> y.Result), obj()) // Exception when executing this

member this.Result with get() = ofp.Value
member this.Source with get() = source // Exception here "The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized"
```

**Edited to add:**
The problem seems to be that the `ToProperty` is causing `ObservableForProperty` to query the "Source" property on subscribe, and F# has checks that the constructor has completed before properties are queried.

**More info:**
In `ReactiveNotifyPropertyChangedMixin.nestedObservedChanges`, the combination of `kicker` and `fillInValue` cause the value to be queried before any change is notified via `PropertyChanged`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ReactiveUI version 5.4.0, there's a new overload to ObservableForProperty that takes a simple non-chained property to monitor.

If you add to that the following extension method:

```
let toPropName(query : Expr) = 
    match query with
        | PropertyGet(a, b, list) -> b.Name
        | _ -> ""

[<Extension>]
type ReactiveObjectExtender =
    [<Extension>]
    static member ObservableForProperty<'u, 't when 'u :> ReactiveObject>(this: 'u, expr : Expr<'t>, ?beforeChange, ?skipInitial) =
        let propertyName = toPropName expr
        this.ObservableForProperty<'u, 't>(propertyName, defaultArg beforeChange false, defaultArg skipInitial true)
```

Then you can observe property changes using the syntax:

```
this.ObservableForProperty(<@ this.MyProperty @>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm, while I'm no F# expert, you might have to eschew ToProperty (it's actually just a helper anyways) and use a read/write property (i.e. one constructed via `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`) and a simple `Subscribe` + property assignment. So Mutable and Gross!

ReactiveUI really likes to initialize properties in the constructor, because it sets up the initial state of the app (if you use `ObservableForProperty`, you'll find that you have to use the `.StartWith` operator all the time or else things won't work until the first time they're changed)

Comment: I'm also no F# expert - but since I like Reactive UI in C#-land, I wanted to use it in F#-land too. I found I can avoid that mutable grossness if I only need to monitor a single (non-chained) property on the ReactiveObject, but it needs to used the Mixin internals. I've sent a pull request for a new overload, together with an example F# snippet that makes it nicer to use. See what you think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ToProperty` with `deferSubscription = true` also solves this.